# asterisk-java and ivr

Tags: java, asterisk, ivr

I know that using asterisk I can have an ivr, that will present the user with some options. But is it possible using asterisk-java make a call that will start this ivr and get the option selected by the user from the menu presented? If so, how can I do that? Or the only option would be to save the selected option to a file and then read it from the java app?

Answer (score 0):

I'd set a channel variable with the user choice in it, and then you can read that channel variable from your JAVA app with an AMI call.  That way you don't need to mess with writing files to disk and worrying about concurrent calls, etc.  Each call holds its own set of required key/values in channel variables, and you just peek/poke them when you need them.